# Loop to append all numbers from an array into a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to append attribute (phone) to my text box (#phone). The response returns 3 phone numbers but only one is appended to the textbox. How can I get all three numbers to append to the textbox like `0044, 0055, 0066`

```
$('#statusFilter').on('change', function() {
  var filter_value = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "user/json/" + filter_value,
    success: function(data) {
      dtListUsers.ajax.url('/admin/dashboard/user/json/' + filter_value).load();
      $.each(data, function() {
        $.each(this, function(k, v) {
          $(#phone).val(v.phone);
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's really easy. This is one way to do it:

Instead of:

```
 $.each(this, function(k, v) {
    $(#phone).val(v.phone);
 });
```

You can:

```
 var phones = '';
 $.each(this, function(k, v) {
    phones += v.phone + ', ';     
 });
 //clean the last comma
 phones = phones.substring(0, phones.length - 1);
 $(#phone).val(phones);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you need is to replace `$(#phone).val(v.phone);` with `$(#phone).val($(#phone).val() + ", " + v.phone);`

Answer (score 0):

You could store your phones in array variable then after the loop appends them to the input with the join character you want :

```
var phones = [];

$.each(this, function(k, v) {
    phones.push( v.phone );
});

$('#phone').val(phones.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code maybe it can help you.

JS CODE -

```
$.each(this, function(k, v) {
    $('#phone').val($('#phone').val()+', '+v.phone);
});
```